# Do While loop In Stream Reader?

Tags: vb.net

Im trying to read the customer information from a text file. But I can only seem to get the first record. Im assuming my issue is coming from each time I click the button it reading from the begining of the file. Is there a way do something like a do while and read the next set of customer information on the button click?

```
Private Sub btnNext_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnNext.Click
    searchFile = File.OpenText("Records.txt")
    Dim CustomerSearch As CustomerAccounts

    Using sr As StreamReader = searchFile
        CustomerSearch.LastName = searchFile.ReadLine()
        CustomerSearch.FirstName = searchFile.ReadLine()
        CustomerSearch.CustomerNumber = searchFile.ReadLine()
        CustomerSearch.Address = searchFile.ReadLine()
        CustomerSearch.City = searchFile.ReadLine()
        CustomerSearch.State = searchFile.ReadLine()
        CustomerSearch.ZIPCode = searchFile.ReadLine()
        CustomerSearch.TelephoneNumber = searchFile.ReadLine()
        CustomerSearch.AccountBalance = searchFile.ReadLine()
        CustomerSearch.DateOfLastPayment = searchFile.ReadLine()

        txtLast.Text = CustomerSearch.LastName.ToString()
        txtFirst.Text = CustomerSearch.FirstName.ToString()
        txtNumber.Text = CustomerSearch.CustomerNumber.ToString()
        txtAddress.Text = CustomerSearch.Address.ToString()
        txtCity.Text = CustomerSearch.City.ToString()
        txtState.Text = CustomerSearch.State.ToString()
        txtZip.Text = CustomerSearch.ZIPCode.ToString()
        txtTelephone.Text = CustomerSearch.TelephoneNumber.ToString()
        txtBalance.Text = CustomerSearch.AccountBalance.ToString()
        txtPayment.Text = CustomerSearch.DateOfLastPayment.ToString()
    End Using
    End Sub
```

Here is my example txt file:

```
ln
Colton
855
134 Street
Scottsdale
az
85260
1234567894
200
11/2/2017
ruca
ln
1234
16553
phoenix
az
8560
1234567894
110
11/9/2017
ln
Delinda
0123
123 Goonight ln
Prescott
Az
86314
1234567894
10
11/20/2017
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's some ugly data there, but nonetheless...I put 3 buttons on a form (btnLoad, btnPrevious, and btnNext) with the 10 text boxes, mocked up your class, and this in your form code:

```
Imports System.IO

Public Class Form1
    Private CustomerSearch As New List(Of CustomerAccounts)
    Private CurrentCust As Integer = 0

    Private Sub btnLoad_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnLoad.Click
        With File.OpenText("Records.txt")
            While Not .EndOfStream
                ' This is fragile if the data lines don't match perfectly to fields and line count
                Dim NewCust As New CustomerAccounts
                NewCust.LastName = .ReadLine
                NewCust.FirstName = .ReadLine
                NewCust.CustomerNumber = .ReadLine
                NewCust.Address = .ReadLine
                NewCust.City = .ReadLine
                NewCust.State = .ReadLine
                NewCust.ZIPCode = .ReadLine
                NewCust.TelephoneNumber = .ReadLine
                NewCust.AccountBalance = .ReadLine
                NewCust.DateOfLastPayment = .ReadLine

                CustomerSearch.Add(NewCust)
            End While

            .Dispose()
        End With

        Debug.Print("Loaded {0} Records.", CustomerSearch.Count)

        If CustomerSearch.Count > 0 Then ShowData()
    End Sub

    Private Sub btnPrevious_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnPrevious.Click
        If CurrentCust > 0 Then
            CurrentCust -= 1
            ShowData()
        Else
            Debug.Print("Already at first record")
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub btnNext_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnNext.Click
        If CurrentCust < CustomerSearch.Count - 1 Then
            CurrentCust += 1
            ShowData()
        Else
            Debug.Print("Already at last record")
        End If
    End Sub

    Sub ShowData()
        Debug.Print("Loading record {0}", CurrentCust.ToString)

        With CustomerSearch(CurrentCust)
            txtLast.Text = .LastName.ToString
            txtFirst.Text = .FirstName.ToString
            txtNumber.Text = .CustomerNumber.ToString
            txtAddress.Text = .Address.ToString
            txtCity.Text = .City.ToString
            txtState.Text = .State.ToString
            txtZip.Text = .ZIPCode.ToString
            txtTelephone.Text = .TelephoneNumber.ToString
            txtBalance.Text = .AccountBalance.ToString
            txtPayment.Text = .DateOfLastPayment.ToString
        End With
    End Sub

End Class

Class CustomerAccounts
    Property LastName As String
    Property FirstName As String
    Property CustomerNumber As String
    Property Address As String
    Property City As String
    Property State As String
    Property ZIPCode As String
    Property TelephoneNumber As String
    Property AccountBalance As String
    Property DateOfLastPayment As String
End Class
```

[image]

Comment: Awesome thank you so much. I was in the process of doing something similar and was stuck. This is for an assignment as this is exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: @BrianneRiggle Please note I made a couple of edits.